# Setup for MS Robotics Studio on 64 bit WIndows

Tags: ccr, robotics-studio

What is the best way to setup Microsoft Robotics Studio 2.0 on 64 bit Windows Vista? Appearently something needs to be done beyond the default installation to get it to run properly.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has released Microsoft Robotics Developer Studio 2008 R3 which includes 64 bit support out of the box, no special install required. It also supports Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0):

According to MRDS requirements Windows 7 is the best OS to run MRDS. If you use Vista, there are high possibilities to find it difficult to run RDS. read more [here](http://www.microsoft.com/robotics/#GetStartedStep1) and [here](http://www.intorobotics.com/lets-start-with-microsoft-robotics-developer-studio-installation-and-components/)